# How to prepare state |+⟩?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Is there a method how to prepare quantum pure state $|+⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0⟩+|1⟩)$ ? Thanks a lot for concrete answer.

Comment: Sure there is, but the specifics depend on what quantum system do you use to encode the qubit. Is it the polarization of a photon? Is it a spin of electron? Is it something else? You need to be concrete yourself, if you want a concrete answer.

Comment: Experimentally? What is the basis for the 0 and 1 states?

Comment: ... and it actually depends on the basis as well...

Comment: On quantum computers based on gate model (e.g. IBM Q), it can be prepared by application of Hadamard gate on state $|0\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming spin basis, prepare an electron with spin up in the z direction using Stern-Gerlach setup. It should be in the desired state along x or y.